# Selecting row (gps-position), when user was at two placed (two rows)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an existing database which I cannot change. Each row is a gps-position with an ID. My problem: I need to select all ids, which are in two bounds.

A simplified example-table:

```
user;position
userA;1
userA;2
userA;3
userB;1
userC;1
userC;1
```

Now I'd like to have all **users**, which are at position 1 **and** 2. That means, only userA, because he has both positions. And yes, userC is twice in position 1, that's correct.

My attempt:

```sql
SELECT user
FROM `test`
WHERE (position = 1 or position = 2)
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(user) > 1
```

Problem: userC is selected too, because it has twice a position in 1

Any ideas? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `sum` clause to your query like

```
SELECT user FROM `test` WHERE (position = 1 or position = 2) 
    GROUP BY id, position HAVING count(user) > 1 AND SUM(position) = 3
```